# Cannot insert duplicate key error when updating EF Core joined tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In my neverending quest to get my databinding to work on this project, I'm having a problem where I bind data in joined tables, but when I attempt to call Update instead of updating it's as if it is trying to insert a new record.

My models and update in the controller are in the dotnetfiddle link below. The binding in question is on model.Product.Tags. model.Product.Tags has the tag count and tags I expect (when I don't change those and just try to save), however, when saving there is a duplicate key error on the ProductTag table. What I want is to update the Product, and if the Tags haven't changed then not attempt any updates to the ProductTag table so would appreciate any pointers on how to achieve this in the best, least hacky way. Thanks

https://dotnetfiddle.net/o9PYvU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
var existingProduct = _context.Set<Product>()
.Include(t=>t.Tags)
.FirstOrDefaultAsync(i=> i.Id=model.Product.Id);

if(existingProduct !=null)
{
Context.Entry(existingProduct).CurrentValues.SetValues(model.Product);

var result = await Context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Update

you can add new Tag this way

```
Context.Entry(existingProduct).CurrentValues.SetValues(model.Product);
if (existingProduct.Tags ==null) existingProduct.Tags= new  List<Tag>();
existingProduct.Tags.Add(newTag);
var result = await Context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Comment: Thanks. That works for my question and allows me to update. If I add a new tag it doesn't save that so how could I keep the existing ones as your answer shows but also allow me to do something like this? model.Product.Tags.Add(myNewTag)

Comment: Thanks for update. That doesn't work for me. The Product I am editing has 3 Tags. I try and add a 4th tag as above and it saves the 3 original tags but doesn't add the 4th one.

Comment: I updated my answer. Hope it  will work for you.

Comment: Yes, that way now works as I want. Thank you!